# Calculate time difference in secs between two cols in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a sample pandas dataframe like below.

```
CID        T1                    Name     T2                        delta 
101    1900-01-01 12:31:58.193    Tom     1900-01-01 12:31:57.193   00:00:01.000 
102    1900-01-01 12:31:57.193    John    1900-01-01 12:31:57.193 00:00:00.000 
103    1900-01-01 12:44:03.098    Mary    1900-01-01 12:34:31.956 -1days+23:50:28.858000 
104    1900-01-01 12:44:03.111    Rocky   1900-01-01 12:31:57.172 -1days+23:47:54.061000
```

I want to calculate time difference taking highest time value and subtracting with lower time value.

```
i.e if t2 > t1 :
  delta = t2 -t1
else: if t1>t2 :
 delta = t1 -t2
```

Also I want the delta value i.e time difference in seconds.

Expected output:

```
CID     T1                    Name    T2                     delta
101    1900-01-01 12:31:58.193  Tom    1900-01-01 12:31:57.193   60s
102    1900-01-01 12:31:57.193  John   1900-01-01 12:31:57.193   0s 
103    1900-01-01 12:44:03.098  Mary   1900-01-01 12:34:31.956  ~600s 
104    1900-01-01 12:44:03.111  Rocky  1900-01-01 12:31:57.172  ~700s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.dt.total_seconds()` on the absolute difference of datetime columns

```
In [877]: (df.T1 - df.T2).abs().dt.total_seconds()
Out[877]:
0      1.000
1      0.000
2    571.142
3    725.939
dtype: float64
```

Comment: perfect!! @John Galt